# issues with elastic beanstalk leader election

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a rails app that has been working fine for months. Today we discovered some inconsistencies with leader election. Primarily:

```
su - "leader_only bundle exec rake db:migrate" webapp
```

After many hours of trial and error (and dozens of deployments) none of the instances in our dev application run this migration. `/usr/bin/leader_only` looks for an environment variable that is never set on any instance (the dev app has only one instance).

Setting the application deployment to 1 instance at a time and providing the value that `/usr/bin/leader_only` expects as an env var works, but not as it has been and should. (Now all instances are leaders so they will fruitlessly run db:migrate and it's 1 at a time, so if we have many instances this will slow us down)

We thought maybe it was due to some issues with the code and/or app, so we rebuilt it. No change.

I even cloned our test application's RDS server and created a new application from a saved configuration, deployed a new git hash, and it never ran db:migrate as well. It attempts to and shows the leader_only line, but it never runs. That rules out code, configuration, artifacts.

Also for what its worth, it never says skipping migrations due to RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS, which has a value of false. This means that it is in fact trying to run db:migrate but isn't due to not being described as the leader.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Please answer your own question if you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @dwilkie we reached out to AWS support via our contract and it's "in progress". All we've heard from our rep is that "it sounds like this is a bigger issue inside of aws for beanstalk" and "looks like we found something". I'll update this page when I hear more.

Comment: Also running into this exact same situation. Any response from AWS?

Comment: There has been response, it looks as if the leader is elected once during the ASG creation and if the leader is lost (due to all instances being lost) then another is never elected. Turns out our issue was from using timed scaling in beanstalk to set instances to 0 at night then back up to 2 in the morning. When there is definitive answer from AWS I will post back.

Comment: If anyone is interested I've posted more information here: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/3hnkzh/anyone_experienced_issues_with_elastic_beanstalk/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have been in talk with the AWS support teams. It seems as though EB leader election is very fragile. 
Per the tech:

> Also, as explained before(Leader is the first instance in an
>   auto-scaling group and if it is removed we loose the leader and even
>   using the leader_only : true in container_commands, db:migrate doesn't
>   work.)

What happened is that we lost all instances. The leader is elected once, and is passed through instance rotation. If you do not lose all instances, everything is fine.

I did not mention a detail. We have many non-production environments, and through elastic beanstalk autoscaling settings, we use timed scaling to set our instance count to 0 at night, and back up to the expected 1-2 amount during the day. We do this for our dev, test, and UAT environments to make sure we dont run at full speed 24/7. Because of this, we lost the leader and never got it back.

Per the follow up from the tech:

> We have a feature request in place to overcome the issue of losing the
>   leader when very first instance is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

> "Elastic Beanstalk uses leader election to determine which instance in
>   your worker environment queues the periodic task. Each instance
>   attempts to become leader by writing to a DynamoDB table. The first
>   instance that succeeds is the leader, and must continue to write to
>   the table to maintain leader status. If the leader goes out of
>   service, another instance quickly takes its place."

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks

Answer (score 0):

In Elastic Beanstalk, you can run a command into a single "leader" instance. Just create a `.ebextensions` file that contain [`container_commands`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands) and then deploy it. Make sure you set the `leader_only` value to `true`.

For example:

***.ebextensions/00_db_migration.config***

```
container_commands:
  00_db_migrate:
    command: "rake db:migrate"
    leader_only: true
```

The working directory of this command will be your new application.

The *leader instance* environment variable will be set by Elastic Beanstalk agent while updating time. It will not be exported to normal ssh shell.

Comment: This makes sense, I've seen that in docker implementations. My question is really: Is this new? We haven't had that, and migrations have worked until Thursday/Friday with no changes to configs or data at all.

Comment: I thought so. I looked for `/usr/bin/leader_only` but couldn't find it in (some random) Elastic Beanstalk environments those are using Amazon Linux 2014.09 and newer.